# Autolayout dynamic textfield width with background

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm trying to setup textfield with background which will be dynamically adopting to text size on UITextField.

This is what I have:

[image]

The problem I have is textfield is increasing it's size to have same width as background, not the other way around.

How can I achieve only 1 way relation ? That will basically always set background width to textfield width, but not other way around.

EDIT:

With UITextField with background I'm getting this:

[image]

Is there any way to define where the backgorund starts, where it stops and what parts of UITextField they have ?

Comment: You can programmatically set the image of the background with resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:

Comment: UILabel doesn't have background property - where you are suggesting to add it ?

Comment: Do pointed the UITextField according to the question description ?

Comment: Ah I'm using UILabel :) I will try switch it to UITextField

Comment: Normally, I used three views to deal with such a requirement, An UIView a, UIImageView b and UILabel c, a contains b and c, c locates above b. Set c's background Color as clearColor. and set resizable image as the image of the UIImageView.

Comment: @Danyun check my EDIT please. How do you setup constrains in this case ? Or you calculate text width programmatically ?

Comment: self.textField.background = [UIImage imageNamed@"youImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets[you cap inset]:resizingMode];